# Eclipse can not compile SOAP WebServices client generated by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, ws-client

I have created a client for my SOAP WebService in Eclipse 4.2.
The project itself (where this client is) was generated by Maven.

Now Eclipse complains about its own generated sources:

```
"org.apache.axis.constants cannot be resolved to a variable"

"javax.xml.rpc cannot be resolved to a type"
```

How to make it compile properly?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the build path doesn't contain all the needed classes, most probably  adding these elements to the classpath would solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I added one of them - for "javax.xml.rpc". I want to add another one - for "org.apache.axis" - but I don't know the correct Maven dependency for this one. And therefore I don't have the correct .jar in my local repository. I found something in Google but did not work.

Comment: `code`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
 <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
 <version>axis-version</version>
</dependency>`code`
This should be it...change the axis-version with the needed version of Axi. If it works, please mark the answer as correct :D.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the referenced projects are in the generated projects build path

Answer (score 0):

Just to add I had the same problem and it was related to Eclipse. I have multiple projects and Eclipse managed incorrectly the classpath when other project is open. I have to close other projects and the classpath defined by pom.xml is properly handled.